# Запросы к БД SQL Server

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста! В виду того что вообще не доводилось работать с базами. Имеется табличка с двумя столбцами оба текстовые. как написать запрос так чтоб ввели значение в один textBox нажали поиск нам в ответ пришло соответствующее ему значение из второго столбца. Заранее извиняюсь если не грамотно задал. Инфы я почитал но всё равно не смог сделать для моего случая.

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public string GetData(string param)
{
    string temp;
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
    { 
        connection.Open();
        using(SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT Param1 FROM Table WHERE Column = {0}", param);
            using(SqlReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    temp += (string)reader[1];
                }
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ыыы, чувак, последняя строчка супер вообще)))

Comment: этот вариант немножко тормозной, я бы быстрее сделал

Comment: да, последняя строка радует))

Comment: Правильное название класса - Sql**Data**Reader.

Comment: В C# нет глобальных переменных, они все - временные, а значит, имя `temp` теряет тот немногий смысл, который оно имело в Pure C.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Column2
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Column1 = 'Какой-то текст для поиска'
```

Где Column1 и Column2 - столбцы таблицы SomeTable